# Git - Creating a JSON text file with key-value pairs and symbols on different lines for having no merge issues

Tags: java, arrays, json, git, keyvaluepair

I have a Java application that populates a JSON object and save it to disk.

The code is like:

```
JSONData = new JSONObject();
    try {
        JSONData.put(KEY,value);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    }
...
```

It's done for data like key-value pairs, arrays and so on. Then

```
JSONText=JSONData.toString();
```

I get a JSON file that is made of one long line of text.

I need, instead, that the resulting JSON file has every single key-value pair in a separate line, also for arrays, and possibly for symbols like [] or {}.

Example:

```
{
"key1":value1, //or even key and value on separate lines
"key2":"value2",
"arrayKey":
[
{
"keyA":valueA,
"keyB":"valueB",
"keyC":
[
0,
1,
2
]
},

{
"keyA":anotherValueA,
"keyB":"anotherValueB",
"keyC":
[
4,
5,
6
]
}
]
}
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: If I may, your assumption that such a file structure would ensure "no merge issues ever" seems unwarranted.

Comment: @RomainValeri see edits

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a replace work on the string, inserting carriage return into it after and before each specified symbol.

I think the problem is more on the git side. Can you explain exactly the problem yo want to solve ?

Comment: Isn't your method prone to splitting strings at positions where similar symbols are legitimate characters in a char-sequence? I think it is not good.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("key1", "value");
        map.put("key2", "value");
        Map<String, Object> innerMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        innerMap.put("hi", "hello");
        innerMap.put("foo", "bar");
        map.put("collection", innerMap);    
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map));
    }
```

**output**

```
{
  "key1" : "value",
  "key2" : "value",
  "collection" : {
    "hi" : "hello",
    "foo" : "bar"
  }
}
```

This will work for all